# How to use .NET Core in Production

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core

We´re on the way to newly develop a WebApplication. We wan´t to make it a ASP.NET MVC app and we thought, that it will be the best approach to start with .NET Core. We started with project type ASP.NET Core WebApplication (.NET Framework).

Has someone experiences with .NET Core in production? How is e.g. Entity Framework used? Is it recommended to use these kind of "mixed" project-types or is it better to wait with .NET Core until all needed functionalities will be available with .NET Core?

I´d highly appreciate your expertise...

Comment: I'm of the mind that, if .NET Core is only at RC status, then you shouldn't be using it for production work.  Consider filing an issue with Microsoft or Hangfire over the Hangfire problem, if you can articulate it more clearly than simply "it doesn't work."

Comment: First: Thank you very much for your answer! Its really helpful to recieve information from someone who have seen much more than I!! FYI: I´ve adressed the Hangfire-Issue directly to the Hangfire-Team at another place. I wanted to provide an example for a current problem, which has, from my perspective, not so much to do with hangfire, but with the usage of such third-party frameworks and new system requirements in general.

Comment: Current .Net Core is not RC, or anything like that. It has been fully released (including tooling). I don't think this can answered in general, it will depend a lot on what you want to do and what tools you want to use. But using new platforms (even after they have been fully released) or less common combinations (like ASP.NET Core on .Net Framework) will always be risky and can run into issues with third party tools.

Comment: I have used .net core (.net framework) in production with EF6 and it works great!  I would not recommend EF Core.  We ran into too many missing features (complex/value objects, etc.) that aren't quite ready.  Separate your  DAL into a regular class library. When .net Core is ready, the switch should be fairly painless.

Comment: @trevorc Thanks for your answer!! Really appreciate your help.. I´ve read a bit of the approach you´re referencing to. I´ve also made a little DAL sample project and it worked as expeceted.. But have you made some experiences with third-party frameworks? And is there something (apart of avoiding ef core) which would be important from your perspective? Thank you!!

Comment: I have recently fallen in love with the CQRS pattern and the MediatR library.  I just started working on a [seed project](https://github.com/trevorchunestudy/netcore-ef6-seed)(shameless plug) that you may find helpful and uses 3rd party .net framework and core libraries.  The documentation and acknowledgments are not done but it should give you some ideas.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @trevorc: CQRS looks amazingly interesting! Thank you.. I´ve got lots of work at the moment, for that reason I need more time to give this some attention. But for now I can tell you, that this was really helpful! BTW: I am a little disappointet, that they have closed my question. Looks a bit like arbitrariness to me.. So much nicer from you, that you gave my question some attention. Thank you!!